# inserting data into a particular section of a configuration file with ansible

Tags: text-processing, configuration, ansible

I have come across a peculiar issue while using ansible. The problem is very strange and dangerous. I have a written a code to insert data in a particular section of a file i.e to add line after `[database]` in say `/etc/cinder/cinder.conf`.

The problem is I have noticed sometimes it adds the content properly after the tag `[database]` , but sometimes it gets confused by seeing a line like `# put ur infore here for [database]`  in the file and adds our required line below it instead of where it should actually put it.

```
   - name: Adding Entries in "/etc/cinder/cinder.conf"
     lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/cinder/cinder.conf"
      insertafter:  "{{ item.inserts }}"
      state: present
      line: "{{ item.lines }}"
     with_items:
      - { inserts: '\[database\]', lines: 'rpc_backend = rabbit' }
```

This situation is quite dangerous in a production environment! How can I add the data correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid matching in a comment, anchor your regexp to the beginning of the line:

```
- { inserts: '^\[database\]', lines: 'rpc_backend = rabbit' }
```

Comment: Oh God !! So silly of me to forget about this,,  thanks a ton ,, I believe this would resolve my concern,,

Comment: @Mohd If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  If you're happy with the answer, accepting it and maybe even upvoting it is the best way to say "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ini_file` module from [`general collection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html):

```
- name: Adding Entries in "/etc/cinder/cinder.conf"
  community.general.ini_file:
    path: "/etc/cinder/cinder.conf"
    section: database
    option: rpc_backend
    value: rabbit
    backup: true
```

To install the collection, run

```
$ ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

or add it to the `requirements.yaml` as

```
collections:
  - name: community.general
    version: 5.0.1
```

and run

```
$ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml
```